# Bootstrap popover is being triggered, but nothing shows

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the example from this [w3 tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover&stacked=h). I implemented it in both my codebase and in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smt0rcLa/), but it does not show the popover content when clicked.

Popover works in Fiddle but not in my environment, but it is being toggled. Here is the HTML element of the non-fiddle one after clicked.

```
<div class="popover fade right in" role="tooltip" id="popover295848" style="top: 80px; left: 193.641px; display: block;">
    <div class="arrow" style="top: 50%;"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">Popover Header</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">Some content inside the popover</div> 
</div>

<div class="popover fade right in" role="tooltip" id="popover503179" style="top: 80px; left: 193.641px; display: block;">
    <div class="arrow" style="top: 50%;"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">Popover Header</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">Some content inside the popover</div> 
</div>
```

If you inspect the Fiddle one there are some slight differences (see: the `::Before`)

Comment: Since it works in JSfiddle, there must be some other code in your environment, be it javascript or css, preventing it from working. There's not much we can do to help solve your problem. Could you replicate your whole code using jsfiddle? We might be able to find the issue if we have all the code in you site...

Comment: It's a very large codebase and one I am new too. However I did find out the actual div element containing the popover content "activates" when clicked and I can see it in inspect. It's just not showing. Any idea why? I tried bringing it to front by increasing z-level and making position both relative and absolute

Comment: It's possible that some css somewhere along the line is overriding the pop over css. What I do in these circumstances, is comment out all css code and css linked files except from the relevant bootstrap css for the pop over, and see if you can get it to work. If it does, add a Bit of css back in bit by bit until it stops working.

Comment: @Studocwho that worked perfectly thanks! Now to find the culprit